# Imagick Error convert tiff to pdf

Tags: image, image-processing, jpeg, imagick, libtiff

When I tried converting a picture via :

```
convert image.tiff image.pdf
```

It thorws the error:

```
convert: no images defined `mosaic.jpeg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3187.
```

I tried installing and reinstalling imagick , libtiff and jpeg. But it didn't help. It used to work on the same machine (Mac Mavericks) but I had to reboot my machine and reinstall everything, and now it doesn't work.
Thank you.

****(UPDATE) Issue Resolved: ****

Installed GraphicMagick instead and worked!

Comment: Can you post the image you are trying to convert somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `homebrew`? If not, I would really recommend it - I use it for everything from ImageMagick to exiftool, ffmpeg, 7zip, openssl, netcat, jhead, gawk, gnuplot, GNU coreutils, GNU parallel etc.

Once you install it, all you do is

```
brew install libtiff
brew install fontconfig
brew install ghostscript
brew install imagemagick --with-fontconfig --with-ghostscript --with-libtiff
```

If you already have `homebrew`, and you installed ImageMagick without any of the extra options, you can do this:

```
brew list      # to see what you have got
brew install <whatever is missing out of libtiff, fontconfig, ghostscript>
brew reinstall imagemagick --with-fontconfig --with-ghostscript --with-libtiff
```

Oh, I forgot to say, your command works fine on my OSX Mavericks with `homebrew`.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, you can also cd into the directory of your image, and use:

```
sips -s format pdf input.tiff --out output.pdf
```

Source:
http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/07/convert-images-using-terminal.html